# Page counter based on address

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to keep track of visitors to a page based on its address/url?

i) Normally, in **PHP**, we have session variables/cookies:

**ex:** $_SESSION['visits']++;

ii) Is there any method to calculate visitors to a particular page, i.e. without having the above code

at each page?

**like:**

```
     if(page_url == '')

     inc++;

     else if(page_url == '')

     inc2++;
```

Comment: Do you want a global page counter or a page counter per session?

Comment: Then you obviously cannot use $_SESSION ;)

Comment: @cularis: Then anything, if the mentioned logic works fine... :)

Comment: If it is not for display purposes, but for finding out how many visits, the easiest would be to use a log analyzer on the web logs.

Comment: @Rasika: Like, if I want to view the no. of visitors to **page3**, in **page1**...?

Comment: This sort of analysis could be easily done by analyzing the access log of the site. Dump it to a database and you can run any complex analysis you want on the data. There are many scripts around to dump the access logs into databases.

Comment: fine... that sounds gr8... thanx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array: `isset($visits[$page_url]) ? $visits[$page_url]++ : 1;`. What it does if there if thats a first visit to an url, it assigns a valute to array with a key $page_url. But then you have to store these values somwhere (probably a database). For a database you need to create a database table or even a set of tables.

But why do it yourself if there is already [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) that calculates visits, unique visits, browser statistics, shows where user has clicked on your page, where user came from and much much more?

[image]